# Mostrar dato dentro de otro de Firebase a un TextView Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase, textview

Tengo un problemita espero puedan ayudarme quiero mostrar un dato dentro de otro de Firebase en un textview en Android Studio y estuve varios días intentando pero nada, no se como hacerlo, el dato en especifico esta como "link" dentro de noticias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cada que agrego una nueva noticia tendrá un link diferente y único, exclusivo para cada uno, entonces cuando haga click por ejemplo en "noticia 2" va a una actividad donde se encuentra el textview y ese quiero que muestre el "link" de "noticia 2" o cuando haga click "noticia 3" va a la misma actividad donde se encuentra el textview y muestre el "link" de "noticia3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de la referencia donde guardas las noticias, vas a necesitar utilizar un metodo que viene integrado a Firebase Database el cual se llama push() , este metodo crea valores alfanumericos aleatorios con un timestamp, asegurando asi que cada valor sea unico.

El proposito como mensione arriba, es el de tener valores aleatorios dentro de tu clave, lo que va a hacer que puedas almacenar mas de una noticia con su link en particular dentro de la noticia.

lo unico que deberias hacer es agregar push() a tu referencia

Por ejemplo, la referencia que creas par las noticias, le agregas otro push pero para cada link

```
mReferencia.child("Noticias").child(idNoticia).child("links").push().child("link").setValue(linkNoticia);
```